# Emoticon blurred in textview with custom background

Tags: android, xml

I got a problem when creating textview with custom background

this is how the problem looks like:
[image: this is how the problem looks like]

i want to make it looks like this:
[image: i want to make it looks like this]

Here is my textview XML code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timestamp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Here is my custom_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#E1E1E1" >
    </solid>


    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"    >
    </padding>

    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Comment: make it transparent. remove solid from custom_bg.xml

Comment: DId you solve this? for me also emojis are blurred with background

Answer (score 4):

Set the color (any color besides transparent) to textview and the emoji transparency problem gets solved:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: You're right, this is because the default color for TextView has some transparency. Setting a new color without transparency solves the problem.